# Where can I find old articles by Paul Erdős?

Tags: online-resources

I am looking for a few old articles by Paul Erdős. I have tried to google the names and have looked for them on other sources like arvix without finding them. I am wondering if anyone knows how I can find these articles. To be more specific I am looking for the 6 first references in the following article : [http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/Cref.pdf](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/%7Ezwsun/Cref.pdf). They are:

1. $[\mathrm{E} 52]$
   P. Erdős, On a problem concerning congruence systems (Hungarian), Mat. Lapok $\mathbf{3}(1952), 122-128 .$ MR $17,14 \mathrm{~d}$
2. $[\mathrm{E} 62]$
   P. Erdős, Remarks on number theory IV: Extremal problems in number theory $I$, Mat. Lapok $13(1962), 228$ - $255 .$ MR $33 \# 4020 .$
3. $[\mathrm{E} 73]$
   P. Erdős, Problems and results on combinatorial number theory, in: A Survey of Combinatorial Theory (J. N. Srivastava et al., eds.), North-Holland Publ. Comp., Amsterdam, $1973,$ Ch. $12,117-138 .$
4. $[\mathrm{E} 77]$
   P. Erdős, Problems and results on combinatorial number theory III, in:
   Number Theory Day (M. B. Nathanson, ed.), Lecture Notes in Math. 626 , Springer, New York, $1977,43-72 .
5. $ [\mathrm{EG}80]$  P. Erdős and R. L. Graham, Old and New Problems and Results in Combinatorial Number Theory, (Monogr.; Vol. 28), L'Enseignement Math. Geneve, 1980. MR 82j:10001.
6. $[\mathrm{E} 81]$
   P. Erdős, Problems and results in number theory, in: Recent Progress in Analytic Number Theory (H. Halberstam and C. Hooley, eds.), Vol. 1, Academic Press, London, $1981,1-14$.

Any information will help!

Comment: [JSTOR](https://jstor.org) has a broad archive of journal articles available. Free access is limited to a certain number of article-reads per month, but that number was bumped to 100 out of consideration for the COVID-19 pandemic. I haven't searched for the specific articles you mention. (BTW: You could/should save readers a click by including the bibliographic information as part of your question.)

Comment: Unrelated to the question: I'm not sure why you're having trouble. I just googled the first 6 references in your linked pdf, and I found pdfs for 5 of the 6 on the first page of google results. The only one that didn't turn up immediately was "On a problem concerning congruence systems", but I suspect that's because it was originally published in hungarian (so that's not its original title)

Comment: You may try this page: https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/Erdos.html

Comment: Gary's link is very comprehensive; the hungarian paper [E52] is https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1952-03.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I would *never* share an illegal platform, where the unscrupulous might find every paper they've hypothetically ever looked for (not that I would be speaking from experience, how dare you suggest such a thing!)

Instead I will drop a wikipedia link which describes such a website.

[Sci-hub wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub)

---

I hope this helps ;)